# Chemical Potential after Freeze-Out

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, chemical-potential, freezing

I've been wondering what happens to the chemical potential $\mu$ of a particle (more specific, a fermion) with a mass m that freezes out around a temperature of $T\sim m$. I understand that the chemical potential is red-shifted if the particle decouples while being highly relativistic or highly non-relativistic and maintains an equilibrium distribution. My intuition would be that the chemical potential of a particle that freezes out and therefore has a constant yield $Y =\frac{n}{s} = const$ ($n$ is the number density of the respective particle and $s$ is the entropy density) is also frozen at the current value. Is this correct or is it necessary to explicitly solve the Boltzmann equations to determine the temperature dependence of the chemical potential? And is there a difference if $\mu = 0$ and $\mu \neq 0$ at freeze out?

Comment: Please specify what the different quantities are.